# Native Android SDK for Bing Maps?

Tags: android, bing-maps

Does anybody know if there is a native **Bing Maps SDK**? I don't really like the idea to use the **AJAX-based** one, as it make the interaction with native code too difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no official Microsoft Android SDK for Bing Maps - the only option is that already given by Peter Knego.

The "official" flavours of Bing Maps SDKs are:

- SOAP web service
- REST web service
- AJAX (v6.3 and v7)
- Silverlight
- iOS
- WPF